# Datatables does not refresh table when searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am working with .search() method in Datatables. Currently I am using it to look for a value in row 0 when a user clicks on a defined buttom. However, when user clicks on this buttom and he wants to go back to watch all table entries again (deleting input text in search box), Datatables does not draw all entries. Here is my code:

```
regExSearch ='^'+event+'$';

// Place the value into the datatable input filter and set focus there.
var tableInput = $('#tableID_filter > label > input').get(0);
$(tableInput).val(event);
$(tableInput).focus();

// Apply the match case (with regex) search manually.
var table = getDatatableInstance('#tableID');
table.column(0).search( regExSearch, true, false ).draw();
```

Datatables code:

```
function fullTableComplete(div, dataSet, columns, orientation, columnsToHide, columnsToExport, sort, pageLength) {

// This function allows you to choose the orientation of the pdf export,
// the columns that must to be hidden and the columns that have not to be 
// exported
$(div).dataTable( {
    "responsive": true,
    "data": dataSet,
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 50, 100, -1], ['5', '10', '50', '100', gettext('All')]],
    "bSort": sortable,
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "pageLength": pageLength,
    "columns": columns,
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": columnsToHide,
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }
    ],
    "buttons": [
        {
            "extend": 'csv',
            "name" : 'csv',
            "exportOptions": {
                "columns": columnsToExport
            }
        },
        {
            "extend": 'pdf',
            "name" : 'pdf',
            "exportOptions": {
                "columns":  columnsToExport
            },
            "orientation": orientation
        }
    ]
});

$('.buttons-csv').html('<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> CSV');
$('.buttons-pdf').html('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF');
```

}

The rest of Datatables are responding correctly so I don't know why when an user dele the search text from input box, datatable does not draw all entries again.

To avoid questions, I write the text to search in input box to do more graphically and intuitive the webpage.

Could someone help me?

Thank you before hand, regards

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the filter by the DataTables API to search for empty string:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable().fnFilter('');
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not a complete solution. This could works if there is some action to catch and apply this API command. However, I just want to get the default Datatables behavior, that is when you delete something from search box, all rows are displayed again automatically. If I don't found anything better I will use it i think.. Thanks!!!

Comment: I was doing tests all day and I have discovered that if I do a search without .column () method, there are not problems and everything works nice. However, if I look for the column (0) as I posted in the code, the problem exists. That is annoying because they have not sense.

Comment: To update this issue: I have posted this problem in datatables forum and even webpage admin have not idea about what is happening. I write url to forum issue for who is interested on it: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46732

Comment: you are storing in var table =getDatatableInstance('#tableID') if you want to draw your table again you should store var table=$("#tableID").datatable({...}) and then write table.column(0).search( regExSearch, true, false ).draw(); i'm not sure what you get by this :getDatatableInstance